# Installed package not found in tab

Tags: lightning, tab

I am using Apto and trying to integrate mailchimp with this platform. Every tutorial I have seen uses a package called "Broker Tools" for this and we have this package installed. Whoever, it seems impossible to find or to use this tab. Is there a step that has to be done before a tab from an installed package can be used?

Comment: did you install the package from app exchange, if yes, please provide the url of that package.

Comment: If in production see if it requires license or is there any app created in App Menu. Also, you can view the components of the package from setup and see if there is any tab in that component list.